# Create outlook category along with mail

Tags: outlook, office365api, outlook-restapi

I need to send a mail along with category by using Graph or Rest API, If that category is not exist for the receiver then it should create and mail should be tagged with created category, any way to achieve this task with graph or rest API?

Answer (score 0):

When e-mail is marked with certain category which doesn't exist in the recipient's mailbox, this category *will not and cannot* be created automatically just by receiving this message.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response.Is it possible to create category for recipients before sending a mail for them? Any other possibilities to achieve this?

Comment: @user1583834 Message categories are something that controlled by user (recipient) client. User is choosing to categorize certain messages or not. This also can be done on the user behalf from add-in for Outlook. Add-in may add certain categories to the master category list.